# How to use C# array to javascript array without converting to json?

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I have a C# array which contains list of C# model:

```
public class AlertInfo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I converted array of C# to json and used in javascript like below:

```
JavaScriptSerializer _serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string result = _serializer.Serialize(myList);
```

in javascript:

```
jQuery.parseJSON('<%= result %>')
```

when `Message` contains double quotation in jQuery.parseJSON method throw exception (for example Message is

> hello "world"

)

Is there any way to handle this error or pass C# array to javascript array in another way??

Comment: No need to parse the value, value is JSON already, try to log the value without `jQuery.parseJSON`

Comment: are you using webmethod?

Comment: no i'm not using webmethods it is just a list that i want to use it in JS

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlEncode function.

Example code:

```
string text = "you & me > them"; // 1

 // Replace > with >
 string htmlEncoded =Server.HtmlEncode(text); // 2

 // Now has the > again.
 string original =Server.HtmlDecode(htmlEncoded); // 3
```

The Output:

```
Step 1: Before encoding has occurred.
String: you & me > them

Step 2: The string is encoded for HTML.
String: you &amp; me &gt; them

Step 3: String is converted back from HTML.
String: you & me > them
```

Or you can use this method in JavaScript side.

Comment: its works well when there is no double cuotations is message property this is my json sample in javascript side [{"Id":"1", "Message":"1233"},{"Id":"2", "Message":"Hello "world""}] when use your sample code? before JSON.parse ?

Comment: Use this method just for Message variable.

{"Id":2, "Message":"Hello &quot;world&quot;"}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
jQuery.parseJSON('<%= result %>')
```

Try simply

```
<%= result %>
```

e.g. it might be part of a statement like `var myVariable = <%= result %>`

Since the serialiser already produced JSON, and JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, it is directly interpretable as a JavaScript variable when it's
part of a JavaScript statement. This means you should be able to just directly inject it into your JavaScript code. It's already JSON, so there should be no need to parse it (as if it were a string).